Creepage and clearance in a dielectric fluid
I'm designing a DC low voltage system ( 1000VDC) with immersion cooling. I have been referring to EN 60664-1 to size clearance and creepage distance, but this standard is ok for air only. Is there any standard or way to extrapolate clearance distances in a fluid different than air?

What you need to look for is the dielectric strength (breakdown voltage for 1 mm of that material).
https://www.google.com/search?q=dielectric+strength+of+fluid+table
For example:

http://www.ydic.co.jp/english/technology/table_E.html

https://infotables.com/physical-tables/96-dielectric-constant-of-liquids-gases-and-solids-table.html


For a high dielectric strength fluid, we usually use mineral oil.

https://soltexinc.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/10/Engineered-Dielectric-Fluids-v-Mineral-Oils-in-Electrical-Cooling-Applications.pdf

